# Speed may increase or decrease when acceleration is positive

Tags: kinematics

I came across a statement in my textbook saying

> acceleration positive indicates velocity increases and speed may increase or decrease

Can you please provide examples for the saying for Speed
I am able to understand the velicity one

Comment: In the 1D case, velocity can be a negative number. If you add a positive increment, the absolute value decreases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we take forward as positive, then $a>0$ means that the velocity is increasing. If the velocity $v$ has "increased" from $-4$ to $-2$, the speed, which is equal to $|v|$, has decreased from $4$ to $2$.